# How I can consider number as a value 1 in C language?

Tags: c

I have a problem in my C program. I need to write a histogram of numbers. If the number on the input will be outside the interval [1, 9], consider such a number as the value 1. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printHistogram_vertical(int *hist, int n);

int main()
{
int i, j;
int inputValue;

scanf("%d", &inputValue);
int hist[inputValue];

for (i = 0; i < inputValue; ++i)
{
  scanf("%d", &hist[i]);
}

int results[10] = {0};

for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  for (j = 0; j < inputValue; ++j)
  {
     if (hist[j] >= 10 && hist[j] < 1)
     {
        results[j] == 1;
     }
     if (hist[j] == i)
     {
        results[i]++;
     }
  }
}

return 0;
}

 void printHistogram_vertical(int *hist, int n)
{
int i, j;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
  printf(" %d ", i);
  for (j = 0; j < hist[i]; ++j)
  {
     printf("#");
  }

  printf("\n");
  }
  }
```

Input:

```
9
3 3 2 3 7 1 1 4 10
```

My Output:

```
 1 ##
 2 #
 3 ###
 4 #
 5 
 6 
 7 #
 8 
 9
```

The correct output:

```
1 ###
2 #
3 ###
4 #
5
6
7 #
8
9
```

If the number is bigger than 10 and smaller than 1 it should count this number as 1. I write this function:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  for (j = 0; j < inputValue; ++j)
  {
     if (hist[j] >= 10 && hist[j] < 1)
     {
        results[j] == 1;
     }
     if (hist[j] == i)
     {
        results[i]++;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is that function ensuring that `inputValue` is equal to `1` when it is not in the bounds of `[1,9]`?

Comment: Look very closely at `results[j] == 1;`. What does this line do? Did you get any compiler warnings and did you read and understand them? Compile with `-Wall`

Comment: `results[j] == 1;`  should count this number as 1. Maybe i need to write another thing here.

Comment: @deadman you didn't anwer my question. What does this statement do? It doesn't do think what you think it does.

Comment: @deadman  Ask yourself this more general question: _what does the statement `a == b;` do?_

Comment: `hist[j] >= 10 && hist[j] < 1` will NEVER be true.  Methinks you need `||` or something like that instead of `&&`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I missed that one. I was too focused on the other issue I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with following condition:

```
 if (hist[j] >= 10 && hist[j] < 1)
 {
    results[j] == 1;
 }
```

1. The comparison  is broken. Value cannot be above 9 **AND** below 1 at the same time. It should be **OR** instead.
2. What should be increment of index 1, is actually comparison `==` of wrong index.

Replacement:

```
 if (hist[j] >= 10 || hist[j] < 1)
 {
     results[1]++;
 }
```

But double `for` loop construction is more complicated than it needs to be. It could be replaced with single `for` loop:

```
for (j = 0; j < inputValue; ++j) {
    int value = hist[j];
    if(value >= 1 && value <= 9) {
       results[value]++;
    }
    else {
       results[1]++;
    }
}
```